# Delete a certain value in a json file

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "Basketball": {
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Jordan"
    },
    "Football": {
        "first_name": "Leo",
        "last_name": "Messi"
    },
    "Football2": {
        "first_name": "Cristiano",
        "last_name": "Ronaldo"
    }
}
```

This is my json file. I want to delete "Football2" out of this json file. It should work no matter what the value of "Football2" is.

So it should look like this after my code is executed:

```
{
    "Basketball": {
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Jordan"
    },
    "Football": {
        "first_name": "Leo",
        "last_name": "Messi"
    }
}
```

This is my code.

```
def delete_profile():
    delete_profile = input('Which one would you like to delete? ')
    with open(os.path.join('recources\datastorage\profiles.json')) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    for element in data:
        print(element)
        if delete_profile in element:
            del(element[delete_profile])

    with open('data.json', 'w') as data_file:
        json.dump(data, data_file)
```

But it gives this error: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `for element in data` returns the dict keys, which are ordinary strings.  You can't delete a string.  You probably wanted `del data[element]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Youre looping over the items in your JSON dictionary unnecessarily when you just want to delete the "top" level items:

```
def delete_profile():
    delete_profile = input('Which one would you like to delete? ')
    with open(os.path.join('recources\datastorage\profiles.json')) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    # No need to loop, just check if the profile is in the JSON dictionary since your 'profiles' are top-level objects
    if (delete_profile in data):
        # Delete the profile from the data dictionary, not from the elements of the dictionary
        del(data[delete_profile])
    # Maybe add an else to handle if the requested profile is not in the JSON?

    with open('data.json', 'w') as data_file:
        json.dump(data, data_file)
```

Comment: Works well! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JuliusJonker Great to hear, if this answer solved your problem, can you accept it?

Comment: Uh how do I do that? welp

Comment: @JuliusJonker You can click the checkmark under the voting buttons on the answer